# Misalignment of bonds in atom with exponent

Tags: chemfig

Normally, I could write H20 with `\chemfig{H-[:30]O-[:-30]H}` which produces:[image]

Beautiful! Now, If I try to add a delta symbol as an exponent, it becomes messy and the bonds does not point to the atoms, instead it points to the exponents!

[image]

How could I possible fix it so the bonds points to the atoms?

Adding pipe `|` to the atoms, `\chemfig{H^{+\delta}|-[:30]O^{-\delta}|-[:-30]H^{+\delta}}`, kind of solves this but the atoms disappeared:[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\charge`:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{H-[:30]O-[:-30]H}

\chemfig{H-[:30]\charge{45:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle-\delta$}{O}-[:-30]H}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sweet! I had to tweak it a little bit, `\charge{90:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle+\delta$}{H}-[:30]\charge{90:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle-\delta$}{O}-[:-30,,1]\charge{80:1.5pt=$\scriptstyle+\delta$}{H}`. I didn't know it was possible to put the delta just above the atom so I did it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try, `\chemfig{H|^{+\delta}-[:30,,1]O|^{-\delta}-[:-30,,1]H^{+\delta}}`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To place a symbol above the atom, use the command \chemabove

In chemistry textbooks, `\delta^+` is written instead of `+\delta`.

```
\documentclass[margin={5mm 5mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{\chemabove{H}{\delta^{+}}-[:30]\chemabove{O}{\delta^{-}}-[:-30]\chemabove{H}{\delta^{+}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]